# how to include a C DLL in a C# application when there are pointers involved?

Tags: c#, .net, c, pointers, dll

I've been trying to include a C DLL in my C# application, for windows mobile 6.5, but I've not been able to obtain a correct behavior.

The function I've been trying to use is the following (As described in the header file):

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllimport) BOOL Init (wchar_t *data);
```

Where data is an input/output parameter.

My code, to include this function, is this:

```
[DllImport(@"ICCardReader.dll")]
public static extern int Init([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ref string data);
```

Altough this is accepted by the compiler when called at runtime this function has a bad behavior (result is always false).

So my question, beside the obvious "have I done something wrong?", is: how to include a C DLL in a C# application when there are pointers involved?

P.S.I've Been able to verify the correctness of the DLL by a third-party application

**[EDIT]**

Thanks to users suggestions I've changed the Dllimport as follows:

```
public static extern int Init(StringBuilder data);
```

Comment: a job for swig (http://www.swig.org/compare.html)?

Comment: I had no idea something like that existed, it is very appealing and i will definitely look into it.

Comment: C# has pointers I would just use them.

Comment: If data pointer passed to function is changed in the function, you may consider using StringBuilder instead of ref string.

Comment: @sardok Yes the string is modified by the function so I've changed the input parameter to StringBuilder but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check what BOOL is defined as.  I suspect this may be a typedef of something else dues to the lack of built in bool in C.

It might be worth trying changing your DllImport to

```
[DllImport(@"ICCardReader.dll")]
public static extern int Init(StringBuilder data);
```

and checking if there is some integer value coming back.

[Edit]
Also try changing the input to StringBuilder

Comment: Thank you for your help Justin. Yes it is defined as integer value but this change hasn't resolved the problem.

Comment: @user1497231 - Update your code to reflect the change.  There is a difference between a `bool` and an `int` in C#.

Comment: @user1497231, So, are you saying you changed your C# definition to return int and it is now returning 0?

Comment: @JustinHarvey Yes that is what appened.

Comment: @user1497231, See edits, try the input parameter as a StringBuilder type.

Comment: @JustinHarvey Yes the string is modified by the function so I've changed the input parameter to StringBuilder but still no change

Comment: @user1497231, I am wondering if the return 'false' is actually indicating that something in the Init function did not work properly.  Have you got any more on what that function might be doing?

Comment: @JustinHarvey That was my first idea but the people gave me a test application for the Dll functions and they works. The Dll uses the serial port to communicate with a card reader.

Comment: So the next question is does the test app populate 'data' in the same way as you, and does it also work on mobile 6.5?

Comment: Hi Justin, I'm sorry but i discontinued that project a long time ago, somewhere around the date of this question, and so I can't answer your question in an adequate manner but thank for your help anyway.